# Objective-C Download file and use it with Document Interaction Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code here, that is incomplete. The First part downloads a file from a URL:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.example.com/pdf/035.pdf";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"035.pdf"];
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        }
```

and puts it in: var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/

Now I want to use this download file with Document Interaction Controller like so:

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"035" withExtension:@"pdf"];

if (URL) {
    // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

    // Configure Document Interaction Controller
    [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

    // Preview PDF
    [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
```

How would I get the file from var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ and display it using Document Interaction Controller ?

Comment: Don't use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"035"...`. Use the same way as before: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` etc.

Comment: Can I get a full example as an anwser please

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? You have the file path, just convert it to an url using `URLWithString:`

Comment: I tried that, but I get this error and my app crashes `'UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme (null).  Only the file scheme is supported.'`

Comment: I changed it to use fileURLWithPath and that worked :)